# Installing pyObjC 2.2 on Mac OS X 10.6 returns GCC-4.2 failure

Tags: python, macos, osx-snow-leopard, pyobjc, gcc4

I'm trying to install pyObjC; it failed with:

```
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccxHurQP.out
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1"
```

I don't have a clue about how to interpret the warnings and error messages. I'd like specific help on this problem, and I'd also appreciate a pointer to any generalized advice on how to install libraries in the future. I always seem to have problems with libraries. (I am coming at this from a PHP/Perl/HTML background, not a sysAdmin or C programmer background.)

I'm running OS X 10.6, Python 2.7.2, and GCC 4.2.1. Here's how I checked my setup:

```
Robin:lego-nxt(0) mikec$python
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Foundation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/Foundation/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: No module named objc
```

Here's the full output from trying to install pyObjC:

```
Robin:~(0) mikec$sudo easy_install pyobjc==2.2
Password:
Searching for pyobjc==2.2
Best match: pyobjc 2.2
Processing pyobjc-2.2-py2.7.egg
pyobjc 2.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyobjc-2.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyobjc==2.2
Searching for pyobjc-core==2.2
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyobjc-core/
Reading http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/software/index.php
Best match: pyobjc-core 2.2
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyobjc-core/pyobjc-core-2.2.tar.gz#md5=91155ec6b319c9b4b066a616dccbdaa2
Processing pyobjc-core-2.2.tar.gz
Running pyobjc-core-2.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-nzE3Ik/pyobjc-core-2.2/egg-dist-tmp-bY1Jak
warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'
warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
libffi-src/x86/x86-ffi64.c:49: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
libffi-src/x86/x86-ffi64.c:379: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
libffi-src/x86/x86-ffi64.c:514: warning: no previous prototype for ‘ffi_closure_unix64_inner’
libffi-src/x86/x86-ffi_darwin.c:39: warning: no previous prototype for ‘ffi_prep_args’
libffi-src/x86/x86-ffi_darwin.c:178: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
libffi-src/x86/x86-ffi_darwin.c:186: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m: In function ‘proto_new’:
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:170: warning: ‘protocol_name’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:38)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:171: warning: ‘protocol_name’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:38)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:177: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:180: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:183: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:184: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:187: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:189: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:193: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:197: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:200: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:204: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:207: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:210: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:214: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:224: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:225: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:230: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:231: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:238: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:239: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:240: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:245: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:246: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:247: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:270: warning: ‘protocol_name’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:38)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:271: warning: ‘protocol_name’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:38)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:274: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:275: warning: ‘protocol_list’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:39)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:278: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:279: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:280: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:285: warning: ‘instance_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:40)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:288: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:289: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:290: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/formal-protocol.m:295: warning: ‘class_methods’ is deprecated (declared at //usr/include/objc/Protocol.h:41)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m: In function ‘-[OC_PythonDate _make_oc_value]’:
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m:188: warning: ‘stringWithCString:’ is deprecated (declared at //System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:386)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m:222: warning: ‘stringWithCString:’ is deprecated (declared at //System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:386)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m: In function ‘-[OC_PythonDate addTimeInterval:]’:
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m:242: warning: ‘addTimeInterval:’ is deprecated (declared at //System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h:27)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m: In function ‘-[OC_PythonDate _make_oc_value]’:
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m:188: warning: ‘stringWithCString:’ is deprecated (declared at //System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:386)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m:222: warning: ‘stringWithCString:’ is deprecated (declared at //System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:386)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m: In function ‘-[OC_PythonDate addTimeInterval:]’:
Modules/objc/OC_PythonDate.m:242: warning: ‘addTimeInterval:’ is deprecated (declared at //System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSDate.h:27)
Modules/objc/OC_PythonObject.m: In function ‘-[OC_PythonObject hash]’:
Modules/objc/OC_PythonObject.m:1218: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:19:31: error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:23:25: error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:24:27: error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
Modules/objc/parsexml.m: In function ‘PyObjCXML_Init’:
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:164: error: ‘LIBXML_TEST_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:164: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:164: error: for each function it appears in.)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:166: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘empty’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m: At top level:
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:181: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:205: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:222: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:547: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:578: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:632: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:677: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:739: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:756: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:784: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:884: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1119: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1353: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1485: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m: In function ‘PyObjC_ProcessXML’:
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: error: ‘xmlDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: error: ‘doc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlReadMemory’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘xmlReadMemory’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: error: ‘xmlNode’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: error: ‘root’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlDocGetRootElement’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘xmlDocGetRootElement’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1606: error: ‘cur_node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1607: error: ‘XML_ELEMENT_NODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1638: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_cftype’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1638: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_cftype’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1640: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1640: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1642: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_class’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1642: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_class’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1648: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_enum’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1648: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_enum’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1654: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_function’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1654: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_function’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1656: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_function_pointer’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1656: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_function_pointer’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1662: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_informal_protocol’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1662: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_informal_protocol’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1668: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_null_const’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1668: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_null_const’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1674: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_opaque’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1674: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_opaque’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1680: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_struct’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1680: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_struct’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1682: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_string_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1682: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_string_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1715: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlFreeDoc’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1715: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘xmlFreeDoc’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:19:31: error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:23:25: error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:24:27: error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
Modules/objc/parsexml.m: In function ‘PyObjCXML_Init’:
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:164: error: ‘LIBXML_TEST_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:164: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:164: error: for each function it appears in.)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:166: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘empty’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m: At top level:
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:181: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:205: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:222: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:547: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:578: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:632: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:677: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:739: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:756: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:784: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:884: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1119: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1353: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1485: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Modules/objc/parsexml.m: In function ‘PyObjC_ProcessXML’:
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: error: ‘xmlDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: error: ‘doc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlReadMemory’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1589: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘xmlReadMemory’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: error: ‘xmlNode’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: error: ‘root’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlDocGetRootElement’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1605: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘xmlDocGetRootElement’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1606: error: ‘cur_node’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1607: error: ‘XML_ELEMENT_NODE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1638: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_cftype’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1638: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_cftype’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1640: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1640: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1642: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_class’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1642: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_class’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1648: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_enum’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1648: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_enum’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1654: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_function’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1654: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_function’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1656: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_function_pointer’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1656: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_function_pointer’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1662: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_informal_protocol’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1662: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_informal_protocol’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1668: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_null_const’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1668: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_null_const’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1674: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_opaque’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1674: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_opaque’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1680: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_struct’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1680: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_struct’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1682: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘handle_string_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1682: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘handle_string_constant’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1715: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xmlFreeDoc’
Modules/objc/parsexml.m:1715: warning: nested extern declaration of ‘xmlFreeDoc’
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccxHurQP.out
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Thank you!